# DB2 How to insert values into a table based on 2 other tables?

Tags: sql, database, db2

I have 3 tables:

Table A : obj_1 (varchar), rlt(varchar), obj_2 (varchar)

Table B : r_id (int), r_obj (varchar)

Table C: obj1 (int), action(varchar), obj2(int)

I need to insert into Table C so it is the exact copy of Table A, except instead of the obj_1 and obj_2 names, it uses the reference number for that object (r_id) from Table C.

```
INSERT into tablec (obj1, action, obj2) ((select r_id from tableb, tablea 
where tablea.obj_1 = tableb.r_obj), (select rlt from tablea), (select r_id    
from tableb, tablea where tablea.obj_1 = tableb.r_obj))
```

Comment: You explanation and sample SQL don't match. Could you please share the proper tables' structures, some sample data and the result you'd like to get from that data?

Comment: @Mureinik done! my bad..

Answer (score 0):

You can use an insert-select statement with a query that joins `reference` and `project`:

```
INSERT INTO tablec (obj1, action, obj2)
(SELECT b1.r_id, a.action, b2.r_id
 FROM   tablea a
 JOIN   tableb b1 ON a.obj1 = b1.r_obj
 JOIN   tableb b2 ON a.obj2 = b2.r_obj)
```

Comment: thanks! this is good and allows me to add multiple rows to all 3 columns. However, because the ON clause is only set for obj_1, in tablec the obj_1 & obj_2 are copies of each other, but really, I need to get the correct b.r_id for a.obj_2 as well, is there a way to do that?

`INSERT INTO tablec (obj1, action, obj2) 
(select b.r_id, a.rlt, b.r_id 
FROM tablea join tableb 
ON a.obj1 = b.r_obj)`

Comment: @Nataly not sure I understood you fully, but if I did, it sounds like you need another `join`. See my edited answer.

Comment: Unfortunately this is what I ended up trying but db2 doesn't allow this.

Answer (score 0):

I had to use a workaround since db2 has certain limitations:
I used 2 temporary views as stepping stones to my goal.

**I do the 2 joins required separately:**

```
create view temp1 (a, b) as (select tablea.p_id, tableb.r_id from tablea
tableb where tablea.obj_1 = tableb.r_obj)

create view temp2 (c, d, rlt) as (select tablea.p_id, tableb.r_id, tablea.rlt
from tablea, tableb where tablea.obj_2 = tableb.r_obj)
```

**then I used one insert statament to combine these 2 based on the PK from tablea**

```
INSERT INTO final (obj_1, rlt, obj_2) 
(select temp1.b, temp2.rlt, temp2.d from temp1 join temp2 on temp1.a = temp2.c)
```